# entity framework 4.1 code first CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: entity-framework

I have created a generic repository project using Entity Framework 4.1 and it works great with my projects when added as an existing project to them but it doesn't work on them when just referenced as dll.

I get this error

> *CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.*

but I have added `app.config` file and set relevant connection string to my SQL Server 2005 database (I have used `DbContext` as type my context)

Please help me.

Here is my connection string :

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="TasksEntities" 
           connectionString="server=(local); database=Tasks; trusted_connection=false; User=sa; Password=****; Persist Security Info=True" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this myself.  The connection string name must match the class name of your DbContext subclass exactly.  If it doesn't EF will not find the connection string and will try and fall back to doing something else (SQL embedded?) which doesn't work on my machine (I have full SQL Server installed).

Comment: That is only if you don't specify a connection string name in the  constructor of your context like this: `public MyDbContext() : base("name=Blah")`

Answer (score 2):

You must verify where is configured your connectionstring if you are working with more than one project for example. If your startup project in your solution has a connectionstring configured and in Package Manager Console is pointing to the project with EF Migrations configured as well (in "Default Project").

You can run with the command in Package Manager **Update-Database -Verbose** what is the startup project and source migration or specify putting the parameters in the command:

Update-Database -SourceMigration MvProject.Data -StartUpProjectName MyProject.Web -Verbose

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your credentials in the connection string should have permission to create database on your server.  Log in to your database server and check whether your user account has the correct permissions. This will be a http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/04/resolving-create-database-permission.html

Comment: it just works fine when its project us added to another and relevant database with mentioned connection string user id is created with no error