# EF Code-First "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'." error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Using MVC and EF Code-First. Question at the bottom, please read on...

I've created a LocalDb database **login** app_user for the application. Don't want the application using the admin (sa) account - for obvious reasons :)

Database login has it's default database pointing to MyDatabase.

I've created a **database user** app_user in MyDatabase.

Added the database user to the **db_datareader** and **db_datawriter** roles. Application needs to read and write to tables.

When the application logs in and accesses the database, the following error is presented:

**CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. Cannot attach the file '....\MyDatabase.mdf' as database 'MyDatabase'.**

Below are my settings...

Web.config

connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User ID=app_user;Password=somepwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Application context Initializer is disabled!

```
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Disable initialization
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }
```

The only reason I can see why Create Database permissions are required is EF expects this if the Initializer is ever enabled! Just a theory!

Workaround: I can get around this error by creating a database user for the app_user login in the master DB, and granting it Create Database permissions. But this would be a security hole, don't want the application login with such permissions.

**Question: Why is the Create Database permission required for the database user?**

Comment: I wonder if the process of dynamically attaching the database is causing a problem? Maybe try a connection string that assumes it is already attached. You could also try a database initializer that uses CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question, it may be an issue related to the class name and database name not matching, which would cause EF to try to create a new database.

[entity framework 4.1 code first CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318353/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-m)

Comment: Just tried this now, i.e. renamed the *connectionstring name* to the same name as the *DbContext class* but still no go.